# angularfire2 - how can use multiple where clauses in firebase?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

```
this.db.list('key_threads/key_threadList', {  
            query: {
                orderBy: "key1",
                equalTo: 'val1', 
                orderBy: "key2",  // I GET ERROR HEARE
                equalTo: 'val2', 
            }
        }).subscribe(
            result => { 
                console.log('result ' + JSON.stringify(result));
           });
```

When I use above code snippet I got error form intellisense:

> [ts] An object literal cannot have multiple properties with the same
>   name in strict mode.
>
> [ts] Duplicate identifier 'orderBy'.

reason to use multiple time orderBy is :

I wont to make query for multiple child in where clouse like

> select * from user where key1='val1' and key2='val2'

Is it no way to implement above SQL query in firebase ?

I use :

angularfire2 : 4.0.0-rc.0

Comment: javaScript objects cannot have duplicate keys. The keys must all be unique

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/26700924/5621827

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in `list` format

Try this

```
query: {
    orderBy: ["key1","key2"],
    equalTo: 'val1'
}
```

Comment: [Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42260757/5621827)